# Calling a function, that yields, twice

Tags: python-3.x, generator, yield

Working with `python3`, I had a requirement:

- Perform some pre-work
- Do the core work
- Cleanup the pre-work

Taking inspiration from `fixtures` in `pytest` I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362900/behaviour-of-pythons-yield/7363045) post and wrote some crazy code.

Though this crazy code works, I wish to understand the `yield` sorcery that makes it working :)

```
def db_connect_n_clean():
  db_connectors = []
  def _inner(db_obj):
    db_connectors.append(db_obj)
    print("Connect : ", db_obj)
  yield _inner
  for conn in db_connectors:
    print("Dispose : ", conn)
```

This is the driver code:

```
pre_worker = db_connect_n_clean()
freaky_function = next(pre_worker)
freaky_function("1")
freaky_function("2")
try:
  next(pre_worker)
except:
  pass
```

It produces this output:

```
Connect :  1
Connect :  2
Dispose :  1
Dispose :  2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "junk.py", line 81, in <module>
    next(pre_worker)
StopIteration
```

What confuses me in this code is, that all the calls to the same generator `freaky_func` is maintaining a single list of `db_connectors`

After the first `yield`, all the objects are disposed and I hit `StopIteration`

I was thinking that calling `freaky_func` twice would maintain 2 separate lists and there would be 2 separate `yields`

**Update**: The goal of this question is not to understand how to achieve this. As it is evident from the comments, `context-manager` is the way to go. But my question is to understand how this piece of code is working. Basically, the python side of it.

Comment: Are you trying to re-invent [context managers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) (a.k.a. `with` blocks)? Your task description sure sounds that way.

Comment: @Tomalak I agree that using context managers is a cleaner way. But I am just trying to understand how this code is working. I mean, calling the function multiple times is appending to the same list and yields multiple times. But it resumes only once ?

Comment: Anyone has insights on this ?

Comment: *"I was thinking that calling `freaky_func` twice would maintain 2 separate lists and there would be 2 separate `yield`s"* - what makes you think that? Nothing in `freaky_func` creates a new list. And nothing in `db_connect_n_clean` yields twice. There is exactly one `yield`, and it is hit exactly once, returning the `_inner` function (which you chose to call `freaky_function` outside) and which adds values to the same list. Trying `next()` once more moves the execution past the `yield`, where your "disposal" loop sits, and then it reaches the end of the function, throwing `StopIteration`.

Comment: There is nothing freaky or strange or magical about it. Think of `yield` as a bookmark. Before calling `next()` the very first time, `db_connect_n_clean` is paused, and the bookmark sits right in front of the first line of the function body. You call `next()`, the function is unpaused and runs up to the next `yield` from this position. After that, the function is paused again, and the bookmark sits right before the next line after the `yield`. You call `next()` again, the function unpauses and runs to the next `yield` (or to the end).

Comment: All that being said, use context managers. Your `db_connect_n_clean` function might be educational, but it's not headed into a place you want to be in. Virtually every database module in Python offers context managers which are designed for this kind of "set up and tear down when done" scenario. Writing your own context managers is not hard, either, no reason to re-invent them (example https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/#creating-custom-context-managers).

Comment: Note that what you have there is a coroutine (well, every generator is a coroutine – but you're actually using it as one) so you might [want to read up on ``async`` in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005651/how-does-asyncio-actually-work), since that's the exact same *mechanism* with nicer syntax (for the full-blown coroutine case, that is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my favorite tools to visualize Python with is [PythonTutor](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20db_connect_n_clean%28%29%3A%0A%20%20db_connectors%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20def%20_inner%28db_obj%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20db_connectors.append%28db_obj%29%0A%20%20%20%20print%28%22Connect%20%3A%20%22,%20db_obj%29%0A%20%20yield%20_inner%0A%20%20for%20conn%20in%20db_connectors%3A%0A%20%20%20%20print%28%22Dispose%20%3A%20%22,%20conn%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0Apre_worker%20%3D%20db_connect_n_clean%28%29%0Afreaky_function%20%3D%20next%28pre_worker%29%0Afreaky_function%28%221%22%29%0Afreaky_function%28%222%22%29%0Atry%3A%0A%20next%28pre_worker%29%0Aexcept%3A%0A%20pass&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false).

Basically, you can see that on the first run  `next(pre_worker)` returns the `_inner` function. Since `_inner` is inside `db_connect_n_clean`, it can access all of its variables.

Internally, in Python, `_inner` contains a reference to `db_connectors`. You can see the reference under `__closure__`:

```
>>> gen = db_connect_n_clean()
>>> inner = next(gen)
>>> inner.__closure__
(<cell at 0x000001B73FE6A3E0: list object at 0x000001B73FE87240>,)
>>> inner.__closure__[0].cell_contents
[]
```

The name of the reference is the same as the variable:

```
>>> inner.__code__.co_freevars
('db_connectors',)
```

Every time this specific function, with this specific `__closure__` tries to access the `db_connectors`, it goes to the same list.

```
>>> inner(1)
Connect :  1
>>> inner(2)
Connect :  2
>>> inner.__closure__[0].cell_contents
[1, 2]
```

The original generator `gen()` is still paused at the first `yield`:

```
>>> gen.gi_frame.f_lineno
6  # Gen is stopped at line #6
>>> gen.gi_frame.f_locals["db_connectors"]
[1, 2]
```

When you advance it again using `next()` it continues on from the `yield` and closes everything:

```
>>> next(gen)
Dispose :  1
Dispose :  2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

If you wish to understand how do generators work in general, there are plenty of answers and articles on the subject. I wrote [this one](https://towardsdatascience.com/cpython-internals-how-do-generators-work-ba1c4405b4bc) for example.

If I didn't fully explain the situation, feel free to ask for clarification in the comments!

Comment: Thank you for the link to visual python. I believe there is a minor typo in your reply `next(a)` should be `next(gen)`